# How Do I Address Other VMs in the VNET By FQDN?

Tags: azure, vnet

I have 2 VMs on the VNET in Azure.

The ports are open in the NSG.

I can access the ports when I use the IP address but I can't access them when I use the FQDM.

e.g.

```
nc -v -z -w2 10.1.2.4 8080
Connection to 10.1.2.4 8080 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

nc -v -z -w2 test.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com 8080
nc: connect to test.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com 8080 port 8080 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
```

The VMs don't resolve the FQDN to IPs within the VNET.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

`eastus.cloudapp.azure.com` is a public DNS name which means communication routes outside of the Vnet. This means you need to add an NSG to allow traffic to port.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDrLY.png)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDrLY.png]

If VMs are on the same VNet and you are using Azure DNS (default) then you should be able to just use the VM name.

Example:

`nc -v -z -w2 VM-hostname 8080`

Answer (score 0):

the existing answer would work, or you could have a domain or a dns server inside the network or you could use [Azure Private DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-overview) for that.

Comment: Can you expand on the answer a bit. e.g. can I set the zone name to be eastus.cloudapp.azure.com so it matches the public dns name? Will that cause any conflicts?

Comment: that would, i believe private dns has to not overlap with public dns, because there is no way to distinguish between dns names

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the VM with its name internally, just do a Ipconfig/all and check the results.

[image]

You can use the DNS suffix along with the VM name. If you VM name is VM1, then you need to use this FQDN: VM1.bgoptsffxguutau1f5u032sm0g.gx.internal.cloudapp.net